# "threadsafe" modifier in JAVA?

Tags: java, thread-safety, grammar, bnf, modifier

I just came across a [BNF Grammar for JAVA](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/JAVA/AJAVA.html). In it, "modifier" has a terminal symbol called "threadsafe". However, I have never seen it before and have not been able to locate that modifier in The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition (docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf). Yet, I found it [here](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/samples/java.glossary.html), describing it in bullet 16 as:

> If another thread excuting this code at the same time can not change the value of a variable then the variable is threadsafe and the compiler may do clever things with it to make the code faster or smaller.

Is this a real modifier? Is it supposed to be introduced in upcomming versions of JAVA?

Comment: No, "threadsafe" is not a modifier. This is just made up stuff on the internet.

Comment: Made me chuckle when I read: "...the compiler may do clever things with it to make the code faster or smaller."

Comment: Mysterious, why (at least) two distinct universities propagate this non-existing modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html), at the official source of Java BNF.

Comment: Thank you! Googling "Java BNF" directly led me to the mentioned University of Geneva's site. Looked trustworthy :)

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, nor is private_protected in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

Both Java and Groovy have keywords like "threadsafe" and "goto" as "reserved tokens" in the compiler, but they have no meaning right now in the language.

Comment: Any references for this? goto I know as it is mentioned in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html but never heard of threadsafe